# If $A$ is a finite dimensional central simple algebra, then $M(A) =\operatorname{End}_F (A)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ be an algebra. For $a, b \in A$ we define maps:

$L_{a}(x) = a x $ and $ R_{b} (x) = xb$

$M(A) = \{\sum^{n}_{i=1} L_{a_{i}}R_{b_{j}} : a_i , b_i \in A ,  n \in \mathbb{N}  \}$

> **Lemma:** If $A$ is a finite dimensional central simple algebra, then $M(A) =\operatorname{End}_F(A)$.

**Proof:** Let $ \{u_{1}, \dots , u_{d} \}$ be a basis of $A$. The operators $L_{U_{i}}R_{U_{j}}, 1 ≤ i, j ≤ d$, are linearly independent. This becomes clear if we rewrite $ \sum^{d}_{i ,j =1}λ_{ij} L_{U_{i}}R_{U_{j}}$as $ \sum^{d}_{i=1} L_{U_{i}}R_{b_{i}}, $where $b_{i} = \sum^{d}_{j = 1} λ_{ij} u_j$. Therefore

$[M(A) : F] ≥ d^{2} = [\operatorname{End}_F(A) : F]$,

and so $M(A) = \operatorname{End}_F(A)$.

> Can you explain about this statement “$[M(A) : F] ≥ d^{2 }= [\operatorname{End}_F(A) : F]$”?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean $\mathrm{End}_F(A)$? In the proof of the lemma in your post, one has already found $d^2$ $F$-linearly independent elements in $M(A)$ (i.e., $L_{u_i}\quad R_{u_j}$ in your post), while $\mathrm{End}_F(A)\cong M_d(F)$ (the $d\times d$ matrix algebra over $F$ where $d=\dim_FA$) has $F$-dimension $d^2$. This is where your questioned statement comes from. To get the result, only to note that elements of $M(A)$ are all endomorphisms of $A$ and the inverse inclusion $M(A)\subset\mathrm{End}_F(A)$ is obvious.